# Why do I get an "No default printer" error when using "ssh lpr" but not when I ssh in?

Tags: linux, ssh, printing, lpr

I have a remote (linux) server that I ssh to from my (also linux) pc to print my stuff.

Everything works if I do:

```
    ssh ${remote_server}
    (now in remote server)
    lpr readme.txt
```

Or:

```
    ssh ${remote_server} lpr readme.txt -P$PRINTER
    (this works too)
```

But if I do:

```
    ssh ${remote_server} lpr readme.txt 
    (I get a "there-is-no-default-printer" error.)
```

I did set the $PRINTER environment variable such that "ssh echo $PRINTER" gives me the right printer name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that running:

```
ssh <host> echo $PRINTER
```

...tells you nothing about the remote environment, because `$PRINTER` will be expanded by your local shell.  On the other hand:

```
ssh <host> 'echo $PRINTER'
```

...will tell you something useful (note the single quotes).

I suspect that what's happening is that you're setting the `PRINTER` environment variable in a file that only gets sourced for interactive logins.  Are you using `bash`?  Or something else?  Where are you setting `PRINTER`?

Comment: You are right, ssh <host> 'echo $PRINTER' produces a blank. I set it in both bashrc and bash_profile. Which is the correct place to set it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `$PRINTER` is set in `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile`, which is ignored for non-interactive sessions.

Your test – `ssh echo $PRINTER` – is invalid, as the variable is expanded *locally*, and what gets executed is `ssh echo printername`.